# What are the steps to solve this calculus problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: Calculus]

I understand that y' is the first derivative, but I'm not really sure how to apply it. Would I move everything to the other side, convert y' to dy/dx and use trig applications to sin/cos? I only took business calculus and have no idea how to solve this.

It would be extremely nice if somebody showed all the steps to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

this is a separable differential equation. you can see this better if you write it as $$x\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\sin y}{\cos y} \to \frac{\cos y \, dy}{\sin y} = -\frac{dx}{x} $$ which can be integrated to give $$\ln \sin y= -\ln x + \ln C $$ that is $$x \sin y = \text{constant}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: compute the derivative of $x\sin y$.